# Postgresql: collapsing a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a Postgresql database, I've got a table of `people`, a table of `jobs`, and a many-to-many table called `people_to_jobs`

I would like to create a query that, for each person, will return the name of their job *when that job is unique*, and substitute a string such as "Multiple jobs" when they have many.

**TABLE 1:** `people`
person_id | person_name
--- | ---
1 | Jack
2   | Sarah
3   | George

**TABLE 2:** `jobs`

| job_id | job_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Accounting |
| 2 | Sales |
| 3 | Research |

**TABLE 3**: `people_to_jobs`

| person_id | job_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |

The desired output would be as follows. Note the value of the second row (Sarah = "Multiple jobs")

**OUTPUT:**

| person_id | person_name | job_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Accounting |
| 2 | Sarah | Multiple jobs |
| 3 | George | Research |

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.person_name, 
    case when count(distinct pj.job_id) > 1 THEN 'Multiple Jobs' else max(j.job_name) end As job_name
FROM people p
INNER JOIN people_to_jobs pj ON pj.person_id = p.person_id
INNER JOIN jobs j on j.job_id = pj.job_id
GROUP BY p.person_name
```